# AADSTS50011 error - The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on

I have an employee who gets this error. However this is only on her own PC - If she changes to another PC she can log in and it works so I guess it's machine-wise, anyone got some suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is the reply URL in the request the same as Redirect URIs in the portal?

Comment: Is there an update?

Comment: Hi, yes i just checked and this is still an issue - I already had the URL sadly :(

Comment: If they are the same, the error should not be reported. So, can you provide a screenshot of the redirect_url you got in your browser and the redirect_url configured in the portal?

Comment: i did just make a new post so you can see the URL is the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently. Like your situation, I have exactly the same URL in my application and in Azure AD, but still have the "AADSTS50011 error".

Finally, this error message is nonsense. I add the following configuration to allow the Azure Application to read all types of user groupe and resolved the problem. (Azure AD application > Token Configuration > add groupes claim):

[image: Screenshot of Azure AD configuration]

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this kind of problem, you can try a general solution:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request url, you will find `redirect_url`, copy the value of `redirect_url` and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with `http`, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer - Ive checked and it was sadly already a part of my redirected URLs

Comment: @JohnsonOG  If they are the same, the error should not be reported. So, can you provide a screenshot of the redirect_url you got in your browser and the redirect_url configured in the portal?

Comment: Get @Carl Zhao - I have posted a picture above!

Comment: @JohnsonOG   1. Make sure that the application you configured in the Azure portal is the same as the application you are using, check your `client id` and compare it.  2.Just keep `https://intranet.prodesigndenmark.com/signin-oidc`, then delete other URLs.  try it out.

Comment: @JohnsonOG  Please try according to the 2 points I said, and then tell me the result :)

Answer (score 0):

As you see here the URL is exactly the same

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]